# Unable to access javascript file (.js) using Service Stack Razor

Tags: razor, servicestack

I'm using Service Stack Razor (ServiceStack.Razor.3.9.45) and I can't access any js nor css file.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
This type of page is not served.
Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.js' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /scripts/bootstrap.js

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044
```

Any help welcome

[Edit] I have the same problem with the RazorRockStar WebHost application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should now be resolved in the latest ServiceStack v3.9.46+ release.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to someone:

Something similar happened to me. In my case i was working with a compiled views application.
After lot of proofs the problem was that js files (and css, etc) has to be marked as "Embedded Resource".